# Adding Javascript Variable Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very simple example below.

**Goal: I'd like monkeyAge & slothAge to both equal 15.**

The issue is when the second variable slothAge is calculated it takes the new firstDataPoint instead of the original value as intended.

What is the correct way to handle this?

```
    var firstDataPoint = 10;
    var secondDataPoint = 5;

    var monkeyAge = firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint; 
    var slothAge = firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint; 

    console.log('monkey' + monkeyAge)
    console.log('sloth' + slothAge)

    Results: 
    monkeyAge = 15;
    slothAge = 20;
```

Comment: You are incrementing `firstDataPoint` each time by using `+=` - i.e you are reassigning `firstDataPoint` to the value of itself plus `secondDataPoint`, i'm not sure that's what you want...

Comment: Same way you would do it with a pencil and paper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this?

```
var monkeyAge = firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint; 
var slothAge = firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint;
```

Comment: Interesting thank you. Why does the "=" mess this up?

Comment: Because you're updating the firstDataPoint value. Basically, you're doing firstDataPoint = firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint, and then monkeyAge = firstDataPoint.

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi See my comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstDataPoint = 10;
var secondDataPoint = 5;

var monkeyAge = firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint; 
var slothAge = firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint;
```

In your example

```
var monkeyAge = firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint;
```

will set firstDataPoint = (firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint), so in subsequent code firstDataPoint is 15.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you just assigned a value in the first calculation to `firstDataPoint` and then in the second calculation you used that variable again (and now its value has changed) and added to it `secondDataPoint`. All of that is due to the `+=` operator.

Let's break your code down :

- `var monkeyAge = firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint;`: can be split into two calculations :

  - `firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint` which increments `firstDataPoint` by `secondDataPoint` due to `+=` so `firstDataPoint` now equals to `15` not `5`.
  - `var monkeyAge = firstDataPoint` which is `15`.
- `var slothAge = firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint;`: can be split into two calculations again :

  - `firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint` which increments `firstDataPoint` by `secondDataPoint` due to `+=` so `firstDataPoint` now equals to `20` not `15` (and not even `5`).
  - `var slothAge = firstDataPoint` which is `20` after all these calculation.

In fact, all that comes from `+=` operator you can change the second calcuation (for `slothAge`) and use only the addition operator.

Here's an example :

```js
let firstDataPoint = 10,
  secondDataPoint = 5,
  monkeyAge = firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint, /** monkeyAge =  15 and firstDataPoint = 15 **/
  slothAge = firstDataPoint; /** equals to 15 **/

console.log('first attempt :')
  
console.log('monkeyAge = ' + monkeyAge); /** output: 15 **/

console.log('slothAge = ' + slothAge); /** output: 15 **/

/** or you can just add "firstDataPoint" and "secondDataPoint" **/

console.log('second attempt :')

firstDataPoint = 10,
secondDataPoint = 5,
monkeyAge = firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint, /** monkeyAge =  15 and firstDataPoint still = 10 **/
slothAge = firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint; /** equals to 15 **/
  
console.log('monkeyAge = ' + monkeyAge); /** output: 15 **/

console.log('slothAge = ' + slothAge); /** output: 15 **/
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var firstDataPoint = 10;
var secondDataPoint = 5;
/**
  Using += actually modifies the value of initial value firstDataPoint by adding the sum of firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint and storing it as the value of firstDataPoint. After your first += operation, the value of firstDataPoint is not 10, but 15.     
**/

//var monkeyAge = firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint;
var monkeyAge = firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint; 

//var slothAge = firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint;
var slothAge = firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint; 

console.log('monkey' + monkeyAge); // 15
console.log('sloth' + slothAge);   // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Using += actually modifies the initial value of **firstDataPoint** by adding the sum of **firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint** and storing it as the value of **firstDataPoint**. After your first += operation, the value of **firstDataPoint** *is not **10**, but **15**.*

```js
var firstDataPoint = 10;
var secondDataPoint = 5;
 

//var monkeyAge = firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint;
var monkeyAge = firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint; 

//var slothAge = firstDataPoint += secondDataPoint;
var slothAge = firstDataPoint + secondDataPoint; 

console.log('monkey' + monkeyAge); // 15
console.log('sloth' + slothAge);   // 15
```